# AJAX, PHP, SQL newsfeed gives error everytime

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

**My Goal**

I am currently working on a newsfeed and I'm working on my ajax knowledge used by jQuery.
I just want that if I post something, people don't have to refresh their page to see the newsfeed. Just like facebook and other social media websites have. I wanna get everything from the database and echo it out, using jQuery AJAX library

**Used languages by me in this topic:**

PHP, SQL, jQuery AJAX,

**My problem**

My problem is that... I've searched for some good codes and I think some might work, but I get an error every time that says:

`Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\__oop\logic\getNewsfeed.php on line 4`

`Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\__oop\logic\getNewsfeed.php on line 4`

I know what it says ofcourse, but I really can't figure it out.

**CODE**

Okay so here is my **AJAX** (As soon as I change `$('.homepage_feed')` to something other, the error disappears, but I need it ofcourse to store to outputted data.):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
    type: "GET",
    url: "logic/getNewsfeed.php",
    dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned
    success: function(response){
        $(".homepage_feed").html(response);
        //alert(response);
    }

    });

});
```

Here is my **PHP** where I select everything and have IN the while-loop an include that is my view (it echo's the html). The error is the $user and the $result query according to SQL error.

```
<div class="wrapper homepage_feed">
<?php

    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$ses_user'"));

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM newsfeed ORDER BY posted_at DESC");

    while ($post = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $avatar     = $post['avatar'] ? '<img src="avatars/' . $post['avatar'] . '" />' : '';
        $imageValue = $post['image'] ? '<img src="uploads/' . $post['image'] . '" class="image_item" />' : '';
        include('views/userFeed.php'); // shows newsfeed

    }

?>
</div>
```

Here is my `include('views/userFeed.php');`:

```
<?php
    // newsfeed & profile content
    // $imageValue checks if there is an image uploaded.
    // if yes, then echo the image, else hide the complete <img> tag.
    echo '
        <article class="newsfeed_item transition">
            <div class="post_avatar">' . $avatar . '</div>
            <div class="user_details" title="'.$post['username'].'"><p>' . $post['username'] . '</p></div>

            <div class="user_text"><p>' . $post['description'] . '</p></div>
            ' . $imageValue . '
            <div class="amount_points_comments">
                <p><span class="points_icon">' . $post['votes'] . '</span></p>
            </div>

            <a href="?action=updateVotes&amp;vote=up&amp;post_id='.$post['postID'].'&amp;user_id='.$user['userID'].'">
            <div class="vote_up_item"></div></a>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </article>
    ';
?>
```

And here is my database setup: http://puu.sh/cTjxs/699b021dc5.png

If anyone knows how I can get rid of those error, that'd be great. I'm really struggling with this. Maybe I don't see something everytime...
Help is a lot appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you instantiating `$mysqli`? The error message is basically saying that you haven't set it to anything in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `$mysqli` is undefined in your code. You use it, but not set any value to it. So the errors told you about it. Look at **examples** of mysql connection setup in [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php).

Comment: In my index I use a switch with a `default: include('logic/getNewsfeed.php');` and above that I include my databases... I could use `global $mysqli;` but that still left my with an error of the fetch of a non-object.

Comment: The point is either that It does work when I remove the ajax, but ajax does something I think that gives the error. The database is good.

Comment: But in your ajax call you're not requesting index.php, you're requesting getNewsfeed.php..?